# Add a simple React form application to an existing Nodejs docker image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a Dockerfile, when run with docker-compose displays 'Hello world' in the browser. Now I want to be able to display a simple react form with some fields to enter text in and a submit button. Is there examples of any simple projects out there that I can just use. How will I update my files, that I have shown below

These are the files that I cam using:

Package.json -

```
 {
  "name": "nodejs-hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "des",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "hh",
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [
    "h"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

index.js -

```
    //now it load express module with `require` directive
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
const PORT = 8080;
//Define request response in root URL (/) and response with text Hello World!
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})
//Launch listening server on port 8080 and consoles the log.
app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('app listening on port ' + PORT)
})
```

Dockerfile -

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json index.js ./

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD node index.js
```

Docker Compose -

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: my-image:1.0
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

https://medium.com/faun/a-simple-docker-setup-for-simple-hello-world-nodejs-application-bcf79bb608a0

What I have now is similar to the example in that link.

Now I just want to be able to display a react form in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your React app and then add this line to copy the src files into the container:

```
COPY . .
```

Also, change the `CMD` (if you're using a CRA) to this:

```
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Thanks, Do you know of an example react form I could follow ?

Comment: That's a loong conversation, I recommend starting with a basic html form and some react tutorial.. I'd also appreciate a +1 if it helped, thanks..

Comment: I am following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qH4pJISKeoI .. would I have to copy everything in from the public and src folders in the video into my container and then do a run npm install and CMD [ "npm", "start" ] ?